# Firebase: onChildAdded() Method called even though offline

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

while testing/debugging, i noticed that when I setValue() some data offline, the onChildAdded() is triggered on my listeners. 
Is it possible to configure the listener so that it only triggered onChildAdded, if the child is really added in the database?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is explained in [this blog post of mine](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/what-happens-to-database-listeners-when-security-rules-reject-an-update.html), with some additional explanations about when security rules are violated.  Changes to Firebase Realtime Database are reflected locally, immediately, and queued for execution on the server, to be finished whenever the device's internet connection allows it.

Your code shouldn't be concerned about whether or not the device is online or offline.  It should just read and write the database regardless, and assume that all the data will be synchronized as soon as possible.  You don't really have an alternative to this in Android/java, unless you want to read and write via the [REST interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).  This is far less efficient and convenient, and doesn't take into account the currently authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks :) Now I understand the whole process better...
"The reasoning is that these immediate callbacks can help your app feel snappy in the face of a poor network connection, and also allows your app to be usable when completely offline."
1. I think that the developer should be responsible for not letting the app feel snappy
2. This way more data will be generated (User wont like it, Firebase earns more money)
3. Most important: If the app crashes, it would be really hard to sync with the database again ...

Comment: The problem I face now because of this (and I dont have any idea how to solve it) .. Lets say i dont have any internet connection ... 

onChildrenAdded will insert the message in the database, app/phone crashes due to different reasons, message wont be sent, but user thinks it has already been sent since it is in the database....

If I only save messages from me if they are successful (onSuccess) then the app can not work simultaneously on another device ...

Comment: Changes to the database will still be synchronized even if the app crashes, as long as persistence is enabled.  The only exception to that is explicit transactions that you write, which can't safely be retried. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Comment: What if the phone crashes or is shut down? Enabling Persistence wont help as far as I understand it

Comment: Also for Example User sends message, User thinks message is sent because of onChildAdded, even though it will be declined ... 
If you wait for onSuccessful and reject all of the users messages in onChildAdded, it wont be synchronized correctly with other Devices...
Of course i can save all the messages i have sent which are not yet successful but this will be more complicated then if onChildAdded only called (please give us the freedom to choose) if it is really added or having further information about the child ...

Comment: The way I described in the blog post is the way that it works.  That can't be changed.  And, like I said, enabling persistence will cause pending writes to be retried at next launch, even in the event of a crash.